# i think move uploaded file is not working even though he can find if the file is existed

Tags: php

If i choose in the same folder of my target directory it said file exist but when i choose in different folder it said success but there`s no file uploaded in that folder here is my code. i get it in google

```
    <?php

if (($_FILES['my_file']['name']!="")){
// Where the file is going to be stored
 $target_dir = "/home/cidinc1802/Pictures/";
 $file = $_FILES['my_file']['name'];
 $path = pathinfo($file);
 $filename = $path['filename'];
 $ext = $path['extension'];
 $temp_name = $_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'];
 $path_filename_ext = $target_dir.$filename.".".$ext;

if (file_exists($path_filename_ext)) {
 echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
 }else{
 move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$path_filename_ext);
 echo "Congratulations! File Uploaded Successfully.";
 }

}
 ?> 
<form name="form" method="post" action="fortesting.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="my_file" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

Comment: what is wrong in my parameter in move uploaded file is not working

Comment: Your `move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$path_filename_ext)` obviously fails for some reason. You never validate it (checking if it returns true or false.) Have you checked your web servers error log? It could be permission issues or something.

Comment: have you tried to copy file using `copy()` function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php and then unlink old file?

Comment: i tried to validate it and i move the echo and now its not showing when i tried to upload. and idk how to check my server log

Comment: the copy function is not working either

Comment: `if (($_FILES['my_file']['name']!=""))`  is not `if($_FILES['my_file']['name']!="")` ?

Comment: go to server > related folder (Pictures) right click on it then go to permission , check all and save then try again